# Can you dynamically request a (cached &) scaled image via imagecache in css?

Tags: 6, theming, media

Is there a way to request a scaled image via imagecache by adding width/height parameters or a preset-reference to the image url within css? For example:

Obviously, to scale down an image in css, you can do the following:

HTML:

```
<figure id="logo"></figure>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {  
  background: url('path/to/image.jpg') no-repeat;  
  width: 50%;  
  height: 50%  
}
```

This will still load the full sized image and scale it down on the client side. I am wondering if something like the following is possible within CSS, so you dynamically request a scaled image via imagecache:

```
#logo {  
  background: url('path/to/image.jpg?width=50px&height=50px') no-repeat;  
}
```

or

```
#logo { 
  background: url('path/to/image.jpg?preset=existingimgpreset') no-repeat;  
}
```

Which will scale down the image on the server side and hopefully will return a cached version of it when possible.

Comment: This is really more suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If so: apologies, but why is that exactly? imagecache is a core-module of drupal and this question is directly related to it

Comment: Yeah I've re-read it twice now, I retract my previous statement :)  Cool thought, wondering what people will say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs imagecache produces are pretty reliable, and contain the name of the preset. Looking at the code in [`imagecache_create_url()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21imagecache%21imagecache.module/function/imagecache_create_url/6) you could build up a path in your CSS that looks something like this:

```
/sites/default/files/imagecache/preset-name/path/to/image.jpg
```

Assuming that your files are stored at /sites/default/files

Comment: This works perfectly and is actually pretty obvious when inspecting image url's in Drupal. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: another question: it seems this only works for files in the /sites/default/files/* directory. I tried doing the same for some images in my theme-dir: `sites/all/themes/mytheme/gfx/imagecache/preset/image.jpg` (and different versions of this url), with no luck. Guess it doesn't work outside of sites/*/files?

Comment: Yeah it uses [`file_directory_path()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_directory_path/6) which returns the files folder...not sure there's any way to change that without editing the module directly